# Invalid named ranges after adding rows in EEplus

Tags: epplus

I'm using named ranges to populate an Excel 'template' with data from my application. When adding rows with InsertRow(), the named ranges of fields below the rows being inserted are not adjusted, resulting in incorrect ranges for those fields. Is this a shortcoming of EPPlus or should I find/correct the named ranges below the inserted rows in my code? (when inserting a row in Excel the named ranges *are* corrected). Or is there any other known workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: If i'm not mistaken; these type of automatic adjustments are more features from excel itself. EEplus only offers you methods to populate an excel file, but you are in charge of making sure everything is setup correctly. I rather prefer this, then eeplus making all kinds of changes on my behalf  and as such losing the precise control i now have.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, EPPlus does not appear to support updating named ranges after a row insert.

I have added an issue for it on their codeplex page [here](https://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/15403). The issue is affecting me too so I'll endeavour to implement it and then make a pull request. Unless or until the library is updated with this functionality I am afraid you will need to manage your named ranges in your own code.